# Reading a 5 Band resistor with Gold as a middle band?

Tags: resistors

[image]

Can anyone read the resistor that the arrow is pointing to?  From what I know you can not have a gold band as a number and if I am reading it correctly it has a tolerance of 0 which does not seem right.

Comment: What you know is defective. Gold and silver are valid multipliers, and a good/complete chart will include them - of course, the internet is full of crud, including many resistor color code sites ignorant of the low-value multipliers. http://www.digikey.com/- and http://www.resistorguide.com/pictures/resistor_color_codes_chart.png/media/Images/Marketing/Resources/Calculators/resistor-color-chart.jpg?la=en-US&ts=72364a89-2139-476a-8a54-8d78dacd29ff

Comment: Well crud. Both those links came up useless when inserted.

Comment: The black band directly on the end cap (rather than the body) is sometimes seen - it indicates the right-hand side of the resistor when you are reading the bands from left to right. As an aside, that first band 'red' could be brown on my monitor anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. Resistor colour codes. Source: [elprocus.com](https://www.elprocus.com/findout-resistor-value-using-resistor-color-code-calculator/).*

From Figure 1 we can easily sort out the red-black-gold-gold as 20 x 0.1 @ 5% tolerence. i.e. 2 Ω, 5%.

The problem is the black band. I can't find any reliable reference to give it as a temperature coefficient. I suspect it's not a standard marking.

Answer (score 2):

I read that as 2 Ohms, 5% Tolerance.
Red   : 2
Black : 0
Gold  : x10<sup>-1</sup> (aka /10)
Gold  : 5%

20x10<sup>-1</sup> = 2

I'm ignoring the lonely black band on the end since the code doesn't seem to make any sense if its included.

The other option is that its not a resistor and its ok for whatever it is to have a black/0 band at the end ...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'd go for example 3 in the picture above and also say 2 ohms with a 5% tolerance. The left most band I would ignore but if you have a meter lift one leg from the PCB and measure it but be sure to compensate from the probe resistance because it will be significant in the low ohms range.

Comment: I wish it was that easy to read.  It fried and I want to replace it instead of buying a new board

Answer (score 1):

I've seen White as a 5th band (military solderable) but I've never seen a Black 5th band.  Wikipedia says it is from the British Standard EN 60062:2005.

Your resistor is \$2.0\Omega\$ with a ±5% tolerance and 250 ppm/deg K temperature coefficient.

[image: Electronic Color Code]

[Electronic Color Code - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code)

Comment: Go on, give the credit for the table or take the credit if you created it yourself. I couldn't find anything reliable with the black tempco.

Comment: That's what makes it interesting.  Learning something new.