# Shunt Resistor Color Code wrong or different

Tags: resistors, shunt, colour-coding

For a project, I was tasked with identifying some components. To identify all the resistors, I use the digikey calculator which so far gave me correct values. However, with that specific resistor shown in the picture, no table was able to correctly guess the correct value.

It is a shunt resistor and the value must be less than 1 Ohm. It also has a higher precision. 
At first reading the values from right to left seemed logical, and I intepreted the middle silver band as white. In the end, I received a value of 690 Ohm, which cannot be.

I am currently thinking that the bands are to be read from left to right with the trailing black band to be ignored. That gives me the more likely result of 0.51 Ohm 0.25%.

My questions are:

- Is my assumption correct.
- What is the reason for using a different color code.

Thanks

EDIT: I added a second picture of a resistor with the same problem. Would be really fantastic if you could help me out.
Thanks
[image: Shunt resistor with 5 bands]
[image: Another shunt resistor with 5 bands]

Comment: Why don’t you measure it and, have you also looked at inductor band codes just in case? What is the PCB ident alongside the component?

Comment: I currently do not have the equipment at hand to measure it accurately. The multimeter only says 0.1 to 0.3 Ohm. The first resistor is used to measure the current of a active power factor correction circuit in a cheaply produced chinese ATX-Power Supply. On the picture is also shown the inductor for the PFC and a heatsink. The second resistor is to measure the current of the two-switch forward converter.

Comment: Can you also (fully) show the white text next to the components?

Comment: I updated the picture. The components identification is R11. J5 as in jumper has been altered. The resistor below has a different ident which is partially hidden beneath the inductor / white stuff.

Comment: Noone can really identify the black band in similar resistor [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225255/reading-a-5-band-resistor-with-gold-as-a-middle-band)

Comment: That means that 0.51 Ohm 0.25% must be the correct value and the manufacturer of the resistor doesn't really care about conventions. Thank you very much. Would you be so kind to take a look at the second resistor as well? Must be a Resistor with less than 1 Ohm as well. One Teacher said something like 0.309 Ohm, but I cannot make any sense of the color code.