# Resistor value from color code?

Tags: resistors

well this is resistor under the microscope. If I read this resistor from A to B direction color code it looks 1,87 ohm 1% tolerance. If I assume that Brown at the B side as a temp. coef. resistor value goes mega ohm rank from [here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225255/reading-a-5-band-resistor-with-gold-as-a-middle-band/225264#225264)  Also while I am measuring with multimeter it show that just 16.2 ohm. I suspect resistance blasted

Which is correct and how to read actual value? and can you guess about resistor watt?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is a resistor? It could be an inductor too.

Comment: Try to reverse engineer a schematic from the relevant section of the board. More context could help.

Comment: If that is a cm scale, then probably 2W.

Comment: @Justme how can be sure that is it resistor or inductor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't match the 5 band color coding scheme for inductors, so that's out.

The [Digi-Key resistor decoder](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code) says 1.86 ohms and 1% tolerance.

That's reading it as brown, gray, blue, silver, brown.

You've interpreted the blue band as violet, but on my screen and to my eyes it is blue.

At any rate, it should be 1.8 something ohms.  If you are measuring 16, then it may be bad.  It is damaged, so that's possible.

It's also possible that your ohmmeter is misleading you.

Short the leads of the ohmmeter.  Write down the resistance value.

Measure the resistor, then subtract the short circuit resistance value from the resistor value.

If that is more than 1% off of 1.86 ohms, then the resistor is bad.

You can estimate the power rating from the size.

[This site has a table of typical sizes and power ratings for resistors.](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-standards-and-codes/resistor-sizes-and-packages/)

Here's the table for through hole resistors:

[image]

It is hard to tell exactly from your photo, but the resistor is something like 10mm in length.  That makes it either 1/2 watt (8.5mm long) or 1 watt (11mm long.)

---

Finbarr correctly notes that 1.86 isn't in any of the numerical series used for resistors.  The nearest is 1.87, which would match the values given in the question.

I'll leave the answer as is, but note that the resistance is probably 1.87 ohms - and that the colors as shown in the photo on the display of my phone are off.

Comment: Hard to say on the blue/purple band from the photo but 1.87 is an E96 value whereas 1.86 isn't even in E192.

Comment: @Finbarr:  I've added a note about the number series.

Comment: On my screen, that blue is showing as definitely blue and I'm on a laptop with a retina display...